# Proving $0$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, with $m$ being a positive integer such that $A^m = 0$ matrix has $0$ as an eigenvalue, but I'm not sure where to start. I also thought that $0$ was not regarded as an eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$  then there is $u \neq 0$ such that $$Au = 0 \to 0 = A^m u = \lambda^m u  $$  therefore $$ \lambda^m = 0 $$ which implies $$\lambda = 0. $$

$\bf edit:$
that is, $A^m = 0$ forces  zero to be  the only eigenvalue of $A.$ there can be no other eigenvalue.

Comment: How do we know there is necessarily a u not equal to zero such that Au = 0? Couldn't there not be a solution to Au = 0?

Comment: @Jorge,  by definition eigenvectors are nonzero. so when we say that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A,$ you are guaranteed to have a nonzero $u$ such that $Au = \lambda u.$

Comment: Right, but how does that guarantees there is a non-zero vector solution to Au = 0?

Comment: @Jorge, please see my edit.